# Angular, Sinon, promises

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon

Can't get my head around angular, sinon and promises. If I need to test something like this:

*myCtrl.js*

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('myCtrl', ($scope, dataService)=> {

   dataService.list('location').then((lst)=> {
      $scope.list = lst;
   });

});
```

*myCtrl-spec.js*

```
describe('testing controller', ()=> { 

   var locations = ['A','B','C'], dataService, $scope;

   beforeEach(module('app'));

   beforeEach(inject($controller, $rootScope, _dataService_, $q) => {
        dataService = _dataService_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        let lstStub = sinon.stub(dataService,'list');
        let promise = $q.defer();
        lstStub.withArgs('location').returns(promise);
   }));


   it('gets locations', ()=> {
      $controller('myCtrl', { $scope, dataService });
      $scope.$digest();
      expect($scope.list).to.be.equal(locations);
   })
})
```

How do I tell Sinon the way the promise gets resolved?

Comment: Note that `$q.defer()` returns a `deferred` object, not a `promise`. You need `deferred.promise` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just pass the `locations` to the spy as resolved promise value with [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when):

```
 lstStub.withArgs('location').returns($q.when(locations));
```

and it should just work fine.  The reason why it is not working in your case is because you are creating a promise from deferred object and never resolving it with appropriate value.

> when(value);
>   Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.

Comment: Just to confirm that you are using ES6 shorthand properties only while initializing the controller @ `$controller('myCtrl', { $scope, dataService });` else it would result in syntax error.